# Custom Download file based on Location

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Is there a way to custom download an excel file from Oracle Apex based on the location? For eg: If I am in Germany, the excel file's currency field(one of the column) should change to German currency and then download from my Apex Report.

Comment: Why only during downloads? Why not as the user is using the application in general?

Comment: If that is possible then it's an add on.